# Resolve android resource @android:color/transparent#00000000

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, xml-parsing, transparent

When I am going to create a new Android Application Project, I keep getting this message.

```
Failed to convert @android:color/transparent#00000000 into a drawable
Failed to parse file C:\Users\vidula\Documents\ADT Bundle\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\platforms\android-4.2\data\res\drawable\item_background_holo_dark.xml
Couldn't resolve resource @android:color/transparent#00000000
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
```

I have updated ADT Bundle to Android 4.2.
What is my error and any suggestions? 
Thank you

Comment: Have you closed your Eclipse and opened it again?

Comment: Yes. I cleaned while the error based xml file is open and then restarted eclipse. But nothing happened.

Comment: Ok, maybe this beter to remove your ADTs and install them again!!!

Comment: Thank you. That would be my last option though.

Comment: I just updated ADT bundle to Android 4.2.2 and the error disappeared. Thank you for comments.

Answer (score 1):

**ex.**  `#CC000000` is the Color code `000000` is your Color hex code. CC is For Transparency.

In the example, `CC` is the hex number for `255 * 0.8 = 204`. Note that the first two hex digits are for the alpha channel. The format is `#AARRGGBB`, where `AA` is the alpha channel, `RR` is the red channel, `GG` is the green channel and `BB` is the blue channel.

I'm assuming that 20% transparent means 80% opaque. If you meant the other way, instead of `CC` use `33` which is the hex for `255 * 0.2 = 51`.

You can take a look at the [Android documentation for colors](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color)

Comment: I just updated ADT bundle to Android 4.2.2 and the error disappeared. Thank you for comments.